# Change span background on hover on another span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change background of second span when I am on first span. I mean when are you on that my row, then menu-settings-img changes background and menu-settings-title changes color of text. I tried doing it in css but I do not know really how to achieve this. Can you help me? My code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <a href="" id="link-settings" href="">
        <div width="80%;">
          <span class="menu-settings-img">
            <img style="width: 4%;" src="{{(career.png) }}">
          </span>
          <span class="menu-settings-title">@lang('main.career')</span>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a container and through container hover do the changes .container:hover > .title { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using css with the `+` selector this way :

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu-settings-img:hover + span {
    background-color: #F0F;
}
</style>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <a href="" id="link-settings" href="">
        <div width="80%;">
          <span class="menu-settings-img">
            <img style="width: 4%;" src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg">
          </span>
          <span class="menu-settings-title">titre</span>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `+` selector points to the next cibling element. see [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) for more informations.

Comment: But when are you on hover of the second span that first span also should change

Comment: your question is not clear to me then. Can you reformulate what you exactly want ?